# Batch merging image files to pdf files using perl in windows

Tags: perl, image-processing, batch-file, merge

I have a bunch of image files in this naming format:

- 313024_Page_1_Image_0001.png
- 313024_Page_1_Image_0002.png
- 313025_Page_1_Image_0001.png
- 313025_Page_1_Image_0002.png
- 313025_Page_2_Image_0001.png

And I would like to convert the files with the same numbers (pre "Page_") to a single pdf with that name. For example, using the above five files:

- 313024_Page_1_Image_0001.png
- 313024_Page_1_Image_0002.png

would merge to 313024.pdf

and

- 313025_Page_1_Image_0001.png
- 313025_Page_1_Image_0002.png
- 313025_Page_2_Image_0001.png

would merge to 313025.pdf

I would like to be able to run this script in Perl in windows.

Thanks in advance,
Jake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) includes a `convert` program that will take `PNG` files and make `PDF` files from them, e.g.:

```
$ convert source.png -compress zip source.pdf
```

You can also `append` image files into a larger image file, before converting to `PDF`:

```
$ convert {listOfImageFilenames} -append -compress zip verticallyStitchedFilename.pdf
```

You can run this within a Perl script via [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) or through the Imagemagick API ([example](http://www.peter.com.au/perl/index.html)).

You'll probably need to adjust these calls for the special way that Microsoft Windows does things, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Can you help me with the script's syntax for this specific problem?